# CoberturaInstrumenter - Unable to instrument file?

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage

My project is using `Java 1.8` and `maven 3.2.1`

I am using `Corbetura` plugin as

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <format>xml</format>
            <maxmem>256m</maxmem>
            <aggregate>true</aggregate>
            <outputDirectory>shippable/codecoverage</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            <reportsDirectory>shippable/testresults</reportsDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

and then I do

```
 mvn clean cobertura:cobertura
```

and I see following

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] 'usePluginRegistry' is deprecated and has no effect. @ /Users/harith/.m2/settings.xml
[WARNING] 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Oauth: Assembling Modules
[INFO] OAuth: Persistence
[INFO] OAuth: Business
[INFO] OAuth: REST
[INFO] OAuth: Integration Tests
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Oauth: Assembling Modules 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ oauth ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) @ oauth >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:instrument (default-cli) @ oauth ---
[INFO] Skipping cobertura mojo for project with packaging type 'pom'
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) @ oauth <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) @ oauth ---
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building OAuth: Persistence 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) @ persistence >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:instrument (default-cli) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Cobertura 2.0.3 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter - Unable to instrument file /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/generated-classes/cobertura/com/self/oauth/persistence/entities/services/OauthEntityManager.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:121)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(Main.java:298)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentation(Main.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:399)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:421)
[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter - Unable to instrument file /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/generated-classes/cobertura/com/self/oauth/persistence/entities/services/OauthEntityManagerProducer.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:121)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(Main.java:298)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentation(Main.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:399)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:421)
[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter - Unable to instrument file /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/generated-classes/cobertura/com/self/oauth/persistence/entities/User.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:121)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(Main.java:298)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentation(Main.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:399)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:421)
[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter - Unable to instrument file /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/generated-classes/cobertura/com/self/oauth/persistence/entities/UserService.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:121)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(Main.java:298)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentation(Main.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:399)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:421)

[ERROR] Aug 13, 2014 11:21:26 AM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler saveCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Saved information on 0 classes.

[INFO] Instrumentation was successful.
[INFO] NOT adding cobertura ser file to attached artifacts list.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/persistence/shippable/testresults
[INFO] Using configured provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.self.oauth.persistence.entities.UserServiceTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.404 sec - in com.self.oauth.persistence.entities.UserServiceTest

Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) @ persistence <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) @ persistence ---
[INFO] Cobertura 2.0.3 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Report time: 40ms

[ERROR] Aug 13, 2014 11:21:28 AM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler loadCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Loaded information on 0 classes.

[INFO] Cobertura Report generation was successful.
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building OAuth: Business 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ business ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/business/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) @ business >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ business ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/business/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ business ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/business/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:instrument (default-cli) @ business ---
[INFO] Cobertura 2.0.3 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter - Unable to instrument file /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/business/target/generated-classes/cobertura/com/self/oauth/business/oauth/ClientRegistrationManager.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:121)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(Main.java:298)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentation(Main.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:399)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:421)
[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter - Unable to instrument file /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/business/target/generated-classes/cobertura/com/self/oauth/business/oauth/TokenManager.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:121)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(Main.java:298)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentation(Main.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:399)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:421)
[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter - Unable to instrument file /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/business/target/generated-classes/cobertura/com/self/oauth/business/oauth/UniqueIdGenerator.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:121)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(Main.java:298)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentation(Main.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:399)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:421)
[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter - Unable to instrument file /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/business/target/generated-classes/cobertura/com/self/oauth/business/outbound/ClientDetail.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:121)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(Main.java:298)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentation(Main.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:399)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:421)

[ERROR] Aug 13, 2014 11:21:29 AM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler saveCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Saved information on 0 classes.

[INFO] Instrumentation was successful.
[INFO] NOT adding cobertura ser file to attached artifacts list.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ business ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ business ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/business/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ business ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/business/shippable/testresults
[INFO] Using configured provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.self.oauth.business.oauth.ClientRegistrationManagerTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.608 sec - in com.self.oauth.business.oauth.ClientRegistrationManagerTest
Running com.self.oauth.business.oauth.TokenManagerTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.15 sec - in com.self.oauth.business.oauth.TokenManagerTest
Running com.self.oauth.business.oauth.UniqueIdGeneratorTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec - in com.self.oauth.business.oauth.UniqueIdGeneratorTest

Results :

Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building OAuth: Integration Tests 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ integration ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/integration/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) @ integration >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ integration ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ integration ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default) @ integration ---
[INFO] Executing commands
[INFO] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:instrument (default-cli) @ integration ---
[WARNING] No files to instrument.
[INFO] NOT adding cobertura ser file to attached artifacts list.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ integration ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/integration/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ integration ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/integration/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ integration ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/integration/shippable/testresults
[INFO] Using configured provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) @ integration <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) @ integration ---
[INFO] Executing aggregate cobertura:report for Oauth: Assembling Modules
Aug 13, 2014 11:21:33 AM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler loadCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Loaded information on 0 classes.
Aug 13, 2014 11:21:33 AM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler loadCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Loaded information on 0 classes.
Aug 13, 2014 11:21:33 AM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler loadCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Loaded information on 0 classes.
[INFO] Saving aggregate cobertura information in /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/oauth/target/cobertura/cobertura.ser
Aug 13, 2014 11:21:33 AM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler saveCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Saved information on 0 classes.
[INFO] Cobertura 2.0.3 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Report time: 42ms

[ERROR] Aug 13, 2014 11:21:33 AM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler loadCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Loaded information on 0 classes.

[INFO] Cobertura Report generation was successful.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Oauth: Assembling Modules ......................... SUCCESS [  0.597 s]
[INFO] OAuth: Persistence ................................ SUCCESS [  3.532 s]
[INFO] OAuth: Business ................................... SUCCESS [  2.784 s]
[INFO] OAuth: REST ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.694 s]
[INFO] OAuth: Integration Tests .......................... SUCCESS [  0.976 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.784 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-13T11:21:33-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/101M
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------
```

at the end it says

```
Cobertura: Loaded information on 0 classes.
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: check target dir, do you see stacktrace that has more info that what you see on console?

Comment: not really. I dont see anything

Answer (score 12):

**Update 05/10/2015**: As of now version 2.7 (apparently) supports this - thanks @tomasz_kusmierczyk

Looks like this is because Cobertura 2.0.3 depends on ASM 4.1, which doesn't support Java 8. I managed to "fix" this by forcing cobertura-maven-plugin to use ASM 5.0.3, but I'm not completely sure that this is the correct way of doing things. It did however get rid of all of those warnings.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            ...
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

The right way to go is probably to use a different code coverage tool, like [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) which is meant to have support for Java 8.

**Update**: Looks like you lose some code coverage info if you go down this route, and so another CC tool is indeed the way to go.

Comment: To clarify what code coverage info you lose / functionality you lose:   1) Code complexity becomes 0 for entire classes if the code has a lambda expression.   2) Instrumentation creates a ton of error output, but still succeeds.  -- From what I can tell, line coverage numbers are still correctly recorded, even within the lambda.

Comment: These days i.e. Oct.2015 you can use version 2.7 of cobertura-maven-plugin and it worked ok, it fixed that '... Unable to instrument file ...' issue for me. Cheers

Comment: I confirm that using cobertura version 2.7 is fixing the problem with JAVA 8. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/FAQ#classnotfoundexception-during-instrumentation:

"This is because during instrumentation in cobertura 2.0, we use ASM to rebuild the .class files. We rebuild the stackmap which is a requirement to be compatible with java 7 and anything after. This does not mean that we recompile the code, however ASM requires that we provide the binaries of the other classes just in case it needs to look up any super methods. To fix this we use an argument called auxClasspath."

Adding the following code to your ant file (build.xml) should resolve the issue.

```
<path id="cobertura.auxpath">
<pathelement location="${bin}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="instrument_coverage" depends="init_coverage"
        description="Instruments source code for coverage measurement">
        <cobertura-instrument datafile="${coverage.datafile}">
            <fileset refid="coverage-files"/>
        <auxClasspath>
              <path refid="cobertura.auxpath" />
            </auxClasspath>
        </cobertura-instrument>
    </target>
```

This worked for me.